# how to show custom results in ngx-pagination and ngx-datatable pages

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable, ngx-pagination

i'm having a problem at hand like this. I have records up to 10 in my JSON output but the client wants to show 32 records like 10 in each page. until, the fourth page and wants the 4th page to show just two records to make up a total record of 32 from the original 10 from the JSON output. Is there a way to do this in Angular ngx-pagination and ngx-datatable.